# PHP: If value is empty, to not sumbit target filepath to database

Tags: forms

I have a very slight problem where I am not able to figure out how to get my target filepath not submit to the mysql database when the field value is empty. Right now, if I leave the image field empty, it still submits the filepath ($folder) to the database. I would like for when the field is left empty, to not send the filepath to mysql.

Form.php

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="add.php" method="POST"> 
HAZARD: <input name="haz1" value="hazard1" type="text" /><br>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" /> 
IMAGE: <input type="file" name="photo"><br>
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Load">
</form>
```

Add.php

```
<?php 
$folder = "images/";

$target1 = $folder . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

$photo = $target1;

require("../db.php");

$haz1 = $_POST['haz1'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO testimg VALUES (null,'$haz1','$photo')") ;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target1);
?>
```

I've tried

```
if (isset($_POST['photo']) ? $_POST['photo'] : null) echo $target1 == null);
```

I've tried other ways of isset as well but doesn't seem to work. Is there any other way i can accomplish this? Appreciate any help please. Thank you!

(Just a note, I have removed excess code above just to keep it short. I am taking care of SQL injection)

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest JavaScript, then users do not need to reload the page if it is empty.  The JavaScript will check if it is empty for you.  If it is you can make it so they cannot submit at all.

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
```

This is an example above, if you would like better walk through [go here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp)

JQuery has libraries that you can use to do fancy things if it is left blank, just search for JQuery form validation for more tools.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the inbuild HTTP_POST_FILE in PHP:

```
if (isset($_FILES['photo']) ? $_FILES['photo'] : null)
```

You could wrap the mysql code inside of an if function too:

```
if (isset($_FILES['photo']) {
    //Do mySQL processing in here
}
```

Comment: @Joe. I do use javascript in most of my code. But in this case, the user is allowed to leave the photo field blank and not upload any pic. However when they do, then I would just like the filepath not to be posted into the database.

Comment: how to I define the $target1 to be blank? right now I am just creating the function

Comment: You can use either $target1 = null; or you can use unset($target1); the latter will mean that when you use isset($target1) it wil return false.

Comment: Sorry I tried with no luck. if (isset($_FILES['photo'])) { $target1 = null; }  and also   
  if (isset($_FILES['photo']) ? $_FILES['photo'] : null) { $target1 = null; }

Comment: I'm not very good at this. Could you please guide me to correct the above code?

Comment: I have made a couple of enhacements and added it as another answer. Also did a few more optimisations.

Comment: If you do it like this above, just create 2 SQL statements, 1 with the photo posting to the database and the second without it.  Doing this there will be no possible way that the database could even get an empty string (or photo).

Answer (score 0):

**A couple of points:**

- Require is at the top of a PHP script. It's nicer to see all requires
  first.
- I have used an inline if statement to determine what to set $photo
  (elimintating need for $target1)
- I have also moved the apostrophes into the assignment of $photo as
  returning 'null' comapred to null (without the quotation marks) is
  very different in SQL.
- If $photo is not null at the end of the script then it moves the
  updated file.

Please see the corrected code below:

```
<?php
require("../db.php");

$folder = "images/";
$photo = (isset($_FILES['photo']) ? "'" . $folder . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']) . "'" : null);
$haz1 = $_POST['haz1'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO testimg VALUES (null,'$haz1',$photo)") ;
if ($photo != null) { move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $photo); }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It still did not work. When i leave the file field empty, /images still posts to the database. I tried modifying a bit but still no luck.

Comment: In that case try replacing the $photo declaration with:

$photo = (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']) ? "'" . $folder . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']) . "'" : null);